# Stripping out fields from Variation in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I'm going to go ahead with what i'm suggesting here, but i thought i'd try and get someones thoughts at the same time

#### Cutting off the fat

I've got several products with **700+ variations**. This becomes an issue with wordpress saving that product because it panics when it tries to save 8000+ fields and causes intermittent saving and ends up losing data.

However, looking at the variations in the backend, there are several fields that i'm not using in each variation:

- weight
- dimensions
- virtual
- downloadable
- stock qty
- sale price (and schedule)

etc.

If i remove these, thats at least 6 x 700 field = 4200 less fields that wordpress has to deal with, which would make saving an actual possibility.

I'm going to just defy the gods for this one and edit the woo commerce template directly to test it out.

I'm not 100% sure how to create a function that would remove these fields without harming woocommerce at this moment in time, if anyone know how, that'd be fantastic

I'll let you know my results.

Answer (score 1):

I just dug around in the `class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php` file and there does not seem to be any easy way to remove built-in input fields. You would probably have to re-write the entire metabox.

What might be possible is a JS solution whereby you remove the fields you don't want. I am not sure at all, but if WooCommerce has proper `isset()` checks on all the variables its save routine then it shouldn't crash.

Or you could remove Woo's save routine and replace it with your own?

Woo's save action:

`add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'WC_Meta_Box_Product_Data::save', 10, 2 );`

This, like re-writing the entire metabox, puts you at risk of things breaking whenever WC is updated.

Just out of curiosity, how does one get 700+ variations?

Comment: The save action might be a good start.

How you get 700 variations = 1 product with 7 colours, 10 variations and 10 sizes :/

Comment: Just to add a note, it's July 2017, I am using the latest woo and in `html-product-data-variations.php`, and I see that it is still not really possible to strip out fields (for example, I want to remove the width, length, height from my variations). Oh well.